# Does VS Code works for Non Salesforce DX?

Tags: salesforce1-app, vs-code

I am trying to search for VS code documentation that works for non Salesforce DX using below plugin
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode

But I am not able to find one.

Comment: Why don't you want to use DX? What alternative API would you use instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing DX won't prevent you from using MavensMate with VSCode.
I've installed the following extensions to VSCode:

- Apex Code Editor for Visual Studio Code
- Apex Debugger for Visual Studio Code
- Lightning Component Code Editor for Visual Studio Code
- mavensmate
- Salesforce CLI integration for Visual Studio Code
- Salesforce Extensions for VS Code
- VisualForce Code Editor for Visual Studio Code

This gives me syntax highlighting and some code completion capabilities. Make sure to add VSCode to your MavensMate setup/config as well though.

I'm not using DX yet because it's not working very well for my group with our highly customized and mature org. So for now we're sticking to MM + VScode + git.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [MavensMate-VisualStudioCode](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-VisualStudioCode), but it involves installing MavensMate. You might also [search the Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=salesforce&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) for other Salesforce-related extensions; many of them do not use DX, and at least a few appear to be completely native with no extra extensions or software required. Also, just in case I've misunderstood your question, DX works on *all* orgs with API access (so, no Personal Edition or Group Edition orgs), including production, sandboxes, developers, and scratch orgs. Setting up a Dev Hub is *not* a prerequisite for using DX.

Comment: Just adding my two cents: I used MavensMate and VSCode together as soon as it became available for VSCode, and really liked it. If someone is opposed to DX, I think @sfdcfox's suggestion is solid. Additionally, the nice thing about Mavensmate is you can use the same MM project in Sublime or Atom.

Comment: @Genko I haven't used MM myself, but I know there's people that swear by it. I've really enjoyed using DX of late, since it allows me to script many of the previously manual tasks of deployment.

Comment: Okay. @sfdcfox I know MM can work for VS Code but there are few issues with MM. For example, it does not gives you Test class coverage details including logs. Code Auto completion is not supported in MM. That is the reason, I was trying to use Salesforce VS code plugin but looks like it is supporting only DX. Please correct me if I am wrong. In that case I like Illuminated Cloud. It is a complete solution for DX and non DX users. But it is a licensed plugin.

Comment: @sfdcfox when using ForceCode or MavensMate, once you save a file, it's automatically compiled and deployed to the "current" org you're connected to. 

Is there any way to do that with DX plugins? 

So far the closest I got from that is saving the file locally, and pushing it manually to my sandbox. I wonder if there's an easier way.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this option was available when you asked the question, but you can now use "Salesforce Extensions for VS Code" and sfdx with sandboxes.

I've set up several sandboxes (and production) using:
"sfdx force:project:create" with parms for each sandbox & production
"sfdx force:auth:web:login" to authenticate each project & set default username
"sfdx force:source:retrieve" to pull down metadata for classes, triggers, pages and lightning components.

Comment: Very true Bryan, I've been using it to good effect against a production copy sandbox. While the MM+VSCode combo worked ok, at this point I would highly suggest switching over to DX+VScode. Here is the github wiki page for the new feature:
https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/wiki/Develop-Against-Any-Org-in-Visual-Studio-Code

Answer (score 0):

ForceCode extension works fine for me.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JohnAaronNelson.ForceCode